# How to revert branch to previous commit with git reset?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally merged in a huge branch into my branch and pushed to the remote repo.

I need to 'reset' back to a previous commit on my branch, before I did this accidental merge.

I've looked at many similar questions on Stack Overflow and they all say to just use

`git reset --hard <sha1_of_where_you_want_to_be>`

which I have done. But I don't see any changes. `git status` shows nothing and when I push back up to my remote repo nothing changes.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I should do next?

Comment: Please _don't_ use hard reset here.  Instead, use `git revert`, following the accepted answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's fine, but then I cannot push it back up to the remote branch as it sees my local branch as behind it. It prompts me to `git pull` which would just pull down the unwanted files again.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, because `git revert` adds a _new_ commit on _top_ of what is already there.  If it sees your local branch as behind, then maybe you need to `git pull` first, then do the revert.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, that did the trick

Comment: For the record, the reason I didn't answer is because I just would have been paraphrasing the duplicate link.  I discourage this, including on myself, so I just left comments instead.

Comment: Yes I understand. The SO questions I encountered did not have the answer your linked to.